# Why is Meteor rendering grid html this way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, grid

I am working on my first Meteor (v1.2.1) project, a webpage that will display three grid sections of html elements with dynamic styling. I think I've implemented the individual grid-item styling correctly, but I'm baffled why the overall page layout is so different from what I'm expecting. To be honest, my knowledge of web design fundamentals like HTML & CSS is poor, so there could be a simple solution that I am oblivious to. Thanks in advance for your help.

The desired layout needs clear divisions between each set and should look something like this:

### "Heading"

Foo Set:
(grid of all foo)

Bar Set:
(grid of all bar)

Baz Set:
(grid of all baz)

When I try to do this with a template and helper functions I get this:
[image]

The first h1 title, "Foo Set", and associated grid are positioned correctly, but the subsequent titles and grids do not separate how I want them too.

Ideally the h1 titles should stay put, and the grids can expand or contract the number of grid-items shown per row based on the browser window size.
In DevTools Elements view I see some things that don't make sense to me. Why is the h1 tag for "Bar Set" taking the dimensions of the Foo grid above it?
[image]

This happens with each div and h1. They seem to reference the dimension of whatever element precedes them. In addition, the divs without IDs for each grid have a width value but zero for their height. My assumption was that these divs would have a height based on the number of grid-items displayed.

Here is my code, minus the server.js and a statusLookup.js file:
viewSets-client.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe('units');

    Template.body.helpers({

        foo: function () {
            return Units.find({TYPE: 'FOO'}, {sort : {ORDERVALUE:1}}).fetch();
        },
        bar: function () {
            return Units.find({TYPE: 'BAR'}, {sort: {ORDERVALUE:1}}).fetch();
        },
        baz: function () {
            return Units.find({TYPE: 'BAZ'}, {sort: {ORDERVALUE:1}}).fetch();
        }
    });

    Template.set.helpers({

        getBackgroundColor: function (elem, status) {
            return Meteor.statusLookup(elem, status);
        },
        getTextColor: function (elem, status) {
            return Meteor.statusLookup(elem, status);
        }
    });
}
```

viewSets.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Set List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>All Sets</h1>
        </header>

        <div id="fooDiv">
            <h1>Foo Set:</h1>
            <div>
                {{#each foo}}
                    {{> set}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="barDiv">
            <h1>Bar Set:</h1>
            <div>
                {{#each bar}}
                    {{> set}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bazDiv">
            <h1>Baz Set:</h1>
            <div>
                {{#each baz}}
                    {{> set}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<template name="set">

        <div class="grid-item" style="background:{{getBackgroundColor 'isBackground' STATUS }}; color:{{getTextColor 'isText' STATUS}}"><span>{{UNIT}}</span></div>

</template>
```

viewSets.css:

```
html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  font-size: 14px;
}

header {
  background: #d2edf4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d0edf5, #e1e5f0 100%);
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Please help me understand how to correctly format my html and CSS rules so the grid sections are separated. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are floating your elements, so things are rendering in the next "free" spot.

To get your h1s in the right place, you need a "clearfix".  which will start things on a new line

see [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: Thank you! Despite lots of googling I never came across "clearfix"... I followed the steps in your link, adding the clearfix CSS and assigning the class to my grid divs and now it all looks great.

Comment: if you use a CSS framework like bootstrap ( and many others also) they provide you with implementations of such things.  But can be good to work all this stuff out for yourself for starters.